# prove that : $∠P A K≅∠ MAQ$

Tags: geometry

prove that : $$∠P A K≅∠ MAQ$$

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: My thought: $AQMP$ is cyclic. Your thoughts?

Comment: As $AQMP$ is cyclic, $MAQ \cong QPM$, but as $m(AKP) = m(MPA) = \pi/2$, it follows that $PAK \cong QPM$, therefore $MAQ \cong PAK$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

As pointed out, APMQ is cyclic. Therefore $\angle 1 = \angle 2$.

The shaded triangle consists of 3 triangles, and they are similar to each other. Therefore, $\angle 1 = \angle 3$